# How to use multiple triggers for multiple calls using "jquery-mentions-input"

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, input, tags

I am using this brilliant plugin http://podio.github.com/jquery-mentions-input/ for my textarea. I am using the default "@" trigger to pull from a list of members, but is there any way to i can use a "#" trigger on the same form to pull from a list of tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration section of the page you posted, there is the **triggerChar** configuration, which you could set to "#".

The settings is the second argument of the initializer, such as :

```
$("#myelement").mentionsInput(method, settings);
```

There is no way currently to accept multiple trigger chars for multiple data sources. This is something you would have to do in their script. I'm pretty sure they would be glad to accept a pull request with that feature added!

EDIT - In fact, there is already a pull request for that : https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input/pull/7

Comment: Yes, i know that, but i want to use two different triggers to do two different things.

Comment: Out of the box you can't, but you could modify their script so it accepts an array of trigger chars and assign a different data source for each of them. Updated my answer to reflect that.